# How to create GLOBAL BRANCH TYPE in cleartype.exe

Tags: clearcase

In TYPE EXplorer [cleartype.exe], how do I create GLOBAL TYPE for a BRANCH TYPE?  I can create ORDINARY BRANCH TYPE in the cleartype.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there might be no obvious way to create a global branch in the GUI cleartype.exe (check if the properties of a created ordinary branch wouldn't have a "global" option to check though), you still can revert to the command-line using [`cleartool mkbrtype`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbrtype.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.2%2F8-0-0-1-35).

```
cleartool mkbrtype -global
```

> Creates a branch type that can be used as a global resource by client VOBs in the administrative VOB hierarchy.
>   With `-acquire`, `mkbrtype` checks all eclipsing types in client VOBs and converts them to local copies of the new global type.